# Scrollbar won't scroll when selected element is out of visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

We have a number of list items in an unordered list of which we can see five at a time. The currently selected list item has its own class ("selected") and when we click up or down, the next list item gets the "selected" class, while the previous one loses it. How do we make it so that when the list item with the "selected" class comes out of the ul's viewable region, the scroll bar will also scroll with the "selected" item?

It scrolls fine with the mouse, but when the up/down buttons are clicked, the selected class changes but it doesn't scroll. In the CSS, the ul is styled with overflow:auto. I've tried changing the overflow but it doesn't have an effect on the result.

EDIT the problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/E7MSN/63/
click enter on the textbox, and a dropdown list will appear. Then using the keyboard up/down arrows, keep going until you reach out of bounds. Notice the scroll does not follow the "selected" element.

Comment: is the js fucntion is clled on keyboard events also

Comment: Yes - it is called on the keyboard events also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scrollTop` to move up and down the `ul` scroll position.
So in your case:

```
$(".services ul").scrollTop($('li').index($(".selected")) * $('.services li').height());
```

In the above code, the `$('li').index($(".selected"))` gets the number of the currently selected `li` element. Then this number is multiplied by the height of each `li`.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7MSN/90/)

You may need to clean it up to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `style="overflow:scroll"`?